# Grab return value to use in an if statement

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```js
function myFunction(clicked_id){
    let playerOne = document.getElementById('player-1').innerHTML = clicked_id
    return playerOne
}
```

My HTML:

`<img id="rock" onClick = "myFunction(this.id)" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Logan_Rock_Treen_closeup.jpg"/>`

The idea is that I grab the id and this is then returned ( only upon click) and then stored into a variable so I can use it in a separate outer if statement on the global scope or other outer function.

I am unable to grab the function's result.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have do define a global variable:

```js
let pressed = ""
function myFunction(clicked_id){
    let playerOne = document.getElementById('player-1').innerHTML = clicked_id
    pressed = playerOne
    return playerOne
}
```

---

EDIT: What you want is not directly possible. You have to put everything that interacts after a click into the event handler.

Comment: when I console log(playerOne) this is saying that the variable is not defined. If I console.log(pressed) it logs an empty value in the console since when the page loads there isn't any value to log until I click it

Comment: Isn't that expected? So the global variable is `pressed`. But it will only be filled when you click.

Comment: it would be if it was filling it in when I click. Upon my click doesn't log anything and if after that function I add an if statement the "pressed" variable is still empty. The idea is that I got a value to grab after function having been called.

Comment: if after this function I do ```if (pressed === "rock"){
    console.log("hey")
}
```
this returns nothing and assumes pressed = ""

Comment: Try adding this code *into* the function.

Comment: yes it works but I want my if statement outside the function for other reasons so I wanted the function to return the value to the global scope so I could then grab that and use it in another separate function that is not this one

Answer (score -1):

Let's look at what you're actually doing:

```js
function myFunction(clicked_id){
    let playerOne = document.getElementById('player-1').innerHTML = clicked_id;
    return playerOne;
}
```

You're setting the inner HTML to the ID (it's an image so I'm very confused why you're doing this, but okay). You then return the ID.

Let's define a variable in javascript:

```
var x;
```

You can then add this into your onclick in HTML:

```
<img id="rock" onclick = "x = myFunction(this.id)" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Logan_Rock_Treen_closeup.jpg"/>
```

Now the function will be run and whenever you click it, the function will run and save the result to `x`, which you can then operate on or use anywhere. Every time you click it `x` will be overwritten.

As a side note, it is not recommended to use inline `onclick=""` and you should try to use JavaScript's [`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#add_a_simple_listener).

Comment: This doesn't work, because the variable is not set at page load. The same problem is with my solution.

Comment: @blaumeise20 wdym? How are you triggering your script?

Comment: @blaumeise20 also that isn't why your solution isn't what he wants